# Как разобрать массив объектов в JS и вывести определенные значения?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Есть такой массив:

```js
const arr = [{
    "moduleId": 2,
    "param": "ws_storage_login",
    "value": "ndb"
  }, {
    "moduleId": 1,
    "param": "next_service_url",
    "value": "http://localhost:8080"
  },
  {
    "moduleId": 0,
    "param": "work_mode",
    "value": "AUTO"
  }, {
    "moduleId": 2,
    "param": "ws_storage_uri",
    "value": "http://domainmode"
  }
];
```

Как из него сделать таблицу, содержащую отсортированные по значению moduleId значения свойств param и value?

Например, чтобы при выборе moduleId === 2 выводилась информация в виде

```html
<p>ws_storage_login: ndb</p>
<p>ws_storage_uri: http://domainmode</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно фильтровать значения массива следующим образом:

```
arr.filter(x => x.moduleId === 2).forEach(x => console.log(x.param));
```

Comment: А как их вывести в JSX, если они приходят с сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Айди в json должны быть уникальными

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const handleSelect = (id) => () => setSelected(id);
  function getDataFromServer() {
    //тут должен быть код, который получает данные с сервера
    setData([
      {
        moduleId: 3,
        param: "ws_storage_login",
        value: "ndb"
      },
      {
        moduleId: 2,
        param: "next_service_url",
        value: "http://localhost:8080"
      },
      {
        moduleId: 1,
        param: "work_mode",
        value: "AUTO"
      },
      {
        moduleId: 4,
        param: "ws_storage_uri",
        value: "http://domainmode"
      }
    ]);
  }
  useEffect(() => getDataFromServer(), []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    {selected && <p>Selected: {data.find(el => el.moduleId === selected).value}</p>}
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>moduleId</th>
            <th>param</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data
            .sort((a, b) => (a.moduleId < b.moduleId ? -1 : 1))
            .map(el => (
              <tr key={el.moduleId} onClick={handleSelect(el.moduleId)}>
                <td>{el.moduleId}</td>
                <td>{el.param}</td>
                <td>{el.value}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit xenodochial-joliot-icl9n]